# Change default terminal shell to root

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, zsh

I was experimenting with my root user on macOS, and performing a zsh installation for the root user and now I can not access my root user. When wanting to enter the school

`sudo su`

The console returns the following message, and I do not know how to fix this problem.

"su: /usr/bin/zsh: No such file or directory"

Comment: what message is shown?

Comment: @MarioKeller I just added the message, I miss it.

Comment: `sudo -s` will start a shell defined in `SHELL` instead of the root's default shell. This will get you up and running as root and be able to fix the real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you, that for the user root the default shell is configured to be /usr/bin/zsh and su is trying to start this programm, but it is not there. 
You can do a

```
sudo /bin/bash
```

to get a root shell and fix your problem. Either copy your zsh to the right location or change the shell for root back to the default. on my mac it is "/bin/sh"

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have zsh installed on mac, try this:

```
brew install zsh
```